# Why "Integrieren bis Unendlich" but not "bis Unendlichkeit"?

Tags: adjective, adverb, mathematics

As far as I know, "unendlich" is an adverb/adjective. And after `bis` should come a noun.

I found

> integrieren bis Unendlich

while I expected

> integrieren bis Unendlichkeit

How is the first citation ok? Can someone explain?

Comment: The infinity sign is labeled "Unendlich" in German.. which truly is a bit weird, you are right.

Comment: How is that different from _bis fünf_ or _bis x_, where x is any number?

Comment: Just consider "unendlich" a (somewhat special) number, and I think you'll be fine.

Comment: To infinity and beyond!

Answer (score 18):

*Unendlich* is used as a "number word" in mathematics like *five* or *ninetynine*

You also say `Die Zahlen von eins bis fünf`, so you can also say `Die Summe von fünf bis unendlich`.

The mathematical symbol ∞ is called *Unendlich*.

Comment: What? The symbol is called "Unendlichzeichen" https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unendlichzeichen

Comment: There is no German word "Unendlich" (as a noun)

Comment: @Adrian: Man sagt auch "Der Pfeil zeigt nach links", nicht so oft "Das Pfeilzeichen zeigt nach links." Bei "Diese Schrift hat kein Euro- und kein Unendlichzeichen" würde man aber weit eher das ~zeichen benutzen.

Answer (score 13):

Actually I see no reason for a substantive there. The word *unendlich* is the appropriate number word on the same level as zero, one, pi and four (which are no substantives either). In German *Unendlichkeit* is the term for philosophy and religion and I find it quite appropriate, to have that separated.

Finally: yes, *integrieren von 0 bis unendlich* is fine (no reason for uppercase).

Comment: It's also *gleich* and *ungleich* in math and not *Gleichheit* and *Ungleichheit*.

Comment: @Janka those are operators though, roughly corresponding to verbs in natural language, where _unendlich_ is a number or an object.

Comment: @Janka *Gleicheit* and *Ungleichheit* are the substantive forms of *gleich* and *ungleich*. Example: "Vektor `Ax` ist *ungleich* `x`. Aufgrund der *Ungleichheit* von `Ax` und `x` kann `A` nicht die Einheitsmatrix sein."

Comment: @guidot The intuition leading to _Unendlichkeit_ is probably that the number is called _(positive/negative) infinity_ in English, and with prepositions as in _bis unendlich_ the reason becomes clear.

Comment: Am Satzanfang schreibt man auch unendlich groß, man muss dann schon umformulieren, wenn man es partout nicht will.

Answer (score 6):

> And after bis should come a noun

... no, not at all:

> *Bis morgen, bis hierher, bis dann, bis fünf, bis unendlich*

where do you see nouns used here?

Nouns are used with **bis + prep.**, e.g.

> bis zum Ende, bis an die Kante, ...

Correct German would be *"bis unendlich"* and "*bis zur/an die Unendlichkeit"*. Only the former is used in mathematics, consistent with other numeral words like *"bis fünf"* (and not *"bis zur Fünf"*)

Comment: **bis + noun:** _... bis Oberkante Unterlippe_, _... bis die Wolken wieder lila sind_